# TensorFlow Lite sample Android app on AOSP

Tags: android, android-source, tensorflow-lite

I have run Android sample TF-Lite app and it works with no error, but if I try to build the same sample app (SpeechActivity part) in AOSP using Android.mk, I've got the following error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.mmiservice/com.mycompany.mmiservice.SpeechActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid handle to Interpreter.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2820)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2895)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1596)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6565)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid handle to Interpreter.
    at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.resizeInput(Native Method)
    at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.resizeInput(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:155)
    at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.resizeInput(Interpreter.java:191)
    at com.mycompany.mmiservice.SpeechActivity.onCreate(DummyActivity.java:143)
```

I have added same downloaded conv_actions_frozen.tflite and conv_action_labels.txt to "/assets" directory and specify it in Android.mk as follows.

```
LOCAL_ASSET_FILES += $(call find-subdir-assets)
```

The error log seems like that the model is not properly loaded into Interpreter.

Could anyone suggest what I did wrong?

Comment: This looks like a bug. Can you post it on GitHub with an example that can be duplicated.

Comment: @NupurGarg, thank you. I will post it to github.